# Fetch all smart contracts created in my Dapp project

Tags: blockchain, solidity, web3js

I am developing a tik tok toe project that is in the form of a dapp, in this project I want to fetch all the contracts created by users, for example 10 users have each created a game on the blockchain platform and I want Fetch these 10 contracts.

I did a lot of research on this topic, but most of my research had the same result. All the sources said the method of listing contracts that were uploaded with a specific wallet, but in this project, each user has his own wallet and uploads contracts from his own wallet.

Comment: You can loop through your list of user addresses and query their smart contracts created by that user address and keep this in a map.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array like so:

```
address [] addresses;
```

In the function where the user creates a new game you can add a new address likes this:

```
addresses.push(newGameAddress);
```

Then you can retrive all data iterating over the array.